# Wpf performance : Reduce lags when using animations

Tags: c#, wpf, performance-testing

I have a few questions related to performance issue in `Windows Presentation Foundation`. I hope experts on SO can help me a bit. I am a student and always open to learning.Anyways,let's get started.

**1 • Animations over PERFORMANCE**

In my wpf app,i have a lot of storyboards which are for different purposes.E.g.

**Changing color of a control from WHITE to GRAY**

**Using ColorAnimation**

```
<Rectangle Fill="White">
 <Rectangle.Triggers>
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
     <BeginStoryboard>
       <Storyboard>
         <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" To="Gray" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
       </Storyboard>
     </Beginstoryboard>
   </EventTrigger>
  </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```

Now,as i run my app,it looks good,fast and ...umm..FINE.The problem starts as soon as i maximize the window.The storyboards starts to lag(not the above one but rather a `ThicknessAnimation`).I knew that by default,wpf sets the refresh rate to `60 FPS`.So i minimized it to `10` with :

```
 Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="10"
```

Now i don't notice the same lag as before.But there is still some lag.Then i came across MSDN forums and other SO qs and found out this :

> Elements where Visibility is not Visible do not participate in input events (or commands), do not influence either the Measure or Arrange passes of layout, are not in a tab sequence, and will not be reported in hit testing.

Reading so,i went on setting `Visibility` of many controls to `Hidden` as soon as any animation is triggered.Being done with the code,i launched my app.Now the performance is,maybe,good because there's still some lag but i can't decide if it is as same as before.Then i came across [this](http://mrpfister.com/journal/improving-wpf-rendering-performance/).I realized that my images which use `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode` might cause such lag,so i set the `BitmapScalingMode` to `NearestNeighbour`(AFAIK this is the lowest rendering quality).I launched my app but still face some lags.The lag may not be an issue/matter of headache for a regular user but for a programmer(i'm a noob tho),it is not acceptable.

Then i kept going through the design area.I noticed a lot of labels and other controls which i added previously.Somewhere online i read that a `Label` has 5 elements whereas a `TextBlock` has 1.So i replaced all `Label`s with `TextBlock`s.Still,i face some lag.

I launched **Word**,**Outlook** and other **Microsoft** products.They seem to have animations but it is hard for me to figure out how these app run way smoother than mine ?

Again browsed the web.Found out that if i use `DataBinding`s(if/when i am working with data-related stuff),that might be in favor of **Performance**.So,within the MainWindow, i added a `ListBox` and set-up dataBinding for it:

**XAML**

```
  <ListBox Name="lstbx1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Margin="0,2">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Names}" />

                                    </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

**C#**

```
  namespace Test.ListBox_control
 {
    public partial class Sample : Window
    {
            public Sample()
            {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    List<TodoItem> items = new List<TodoItem>();
                    items.Add(new TodoItem() { Title = "Complete this WPF tutorial", Completion = 45 });
                    items.Add(new TodoItem() { Title = "Learn C#", Completion = 80 });
                    items.Add(new TodoItem() { Title = "Wash the car", Completion = 0 });

                    lstbx1.ItemsSource = items;
            }
    }

    public class TodoItem
    {
            public string Name{ get; set; }

    }
  }
```

Good,there's no issue with the listbox.But wait,am i not supposed to check the animations....!! And again they disappoint me.The animations are still slow.My laptop specs are : 8 gb ram,4gb Intel HD Graphics 520,i5 6200U 2.3 ghz cpu..I am afraid if my app lags on this machine,what might happen if a user tries to run it on a low-specs system ?

**Conclusion**

This post maybe voted to be closed as it may be too broad but can someone please answer my question : Are there more efficient ways to get rid of these lags ? And how does big softwares like Office have same animations as i do but dont have the lags ? Is it because i am using c# and the are using c++(maybe) ?

Comment: To avoid being closed as too broad, you may want to edit your question to better reflect a problem statement that has a definitive answer. Perhaps something like "How can I remove lag from storyboards?" Focus more specifically on your problem and get away from comparing to office.

Comment: why not to compare to office sir ?

Comment: It is fine to leave one comment describing that you are looking for office-like behavior, but "And how does big softwares like Office have same animations as i do but dont have the lags ?" would be too broad to answer.

Comment: i understand but sir,can u please explain in a few words how they work ? Or some piece of advice on performance?

Comment: Unfortunately I have neither the experience nor knowledge to help with this one. Just thought I'd leave a comment to help avoiding this from being closed. I think the question (focusing solely on your storyboards lagging) is a good question, its the extra bits that are perhaps too broad.

Comment: Yes,i've edited the title to address my exact problem..tnx

Comment: I'm not an animation ninja, but what I see is that you definitely need to sharp your profiling skills. You have a great profiler for WPF performance issues under: Debug->Profiler->Performance Profiler... -> Application Timeline

Comment: The profiler @MaciekŚ. specified is your best bet. Often times with WPF bindings you get tons of recursion and and calls to events you don't actually want called. These things can add up and effect your render performance. When you profile you can see the called events. Look for things that are called an abnormal amount of times, or things that take a lot of time to run and go from there.